# bxSlider main image disappears when js animation is triggered

Tags: bxslider

I have spent a great deal of time trying to create a variation of bxSlider that will use a container to hold the thumbnails that access the main image in the slider so that I can animate this container with "next" and "previous" buttons that use js. It is supposed to only animate the contents of the div labelled "class='scrollable'", but it is affecting the main image of the slider as well, making it disappear and not allowing it to be accessed in any other way after the initial click on one of the buttons. Below is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#next").click(function () {
        $('.scrollable').animate({
            scrollLeft: '+=220'
        }, "slow");
    });
    $("#prev").click(function () {
       $('.scrollable').animate({
            scrollLeft: '-=220'
        }, "slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

which is in my header above the bxSlider code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){    
$('.slides').bxSlider({
  auto: false,
  autoStart: false,
  autoHover: true,
  mode: 'fade',
  controls: true,
  captions: true,
  pause: 5000,
  speed: 500,
  pager: true,
        buildPager: null,
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
});
  });
</script>
```

then in my html, my slider looks like this:

```
<ul class="slides">
<li><img src="01.jpg" border="0" />
<div class="bx-caption">CAPTION</div></li>
<li><img src="02.jpg" border="0" />
<div class="bx-caption">CAPTION</div></li>
</ul>

<div id="bx-pager">

<div class="scrollable">
<div class="controller"><a href="#" id="prev">PREVIOUS</a><a href="#" id="next">NEXT</a> </div>             
<div class="scrollme">
<a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="01.jpg" /></a>
<a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="02.jpg" /></a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

It seems to me that technically, nothing should be animated that isn't inside .scrollable, but the image inside  disappears when you click on either the "next" or "prev" buttons. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen or how to override it?

Comment: i can also upload the entire sample page to a test site if that will help.